# How to set Interpreter flags when packaging

Tags: python, optimization, pip, compiler-flags, python-packaging

I want to set the `-O` flag, so that when the package will be build the code will be optimized.

I use the setuptools for building the package and it whould be good to set the optimization flag here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup.py build_py` has an option `optimize`:

```
$ python setup.py build_py --help | grep -A1 optimize
  --optimize (-O)   also compile with optimization: -O1 for "python -O", -O2
                    for "python -OO", and -O0 to disable [default: -O0]
```

It also works for `setup.py install`. For `pip` pass `--install-option=-O1`

But please bear in mind the optimization perhaps doesn't do what you expect it to do and also could make things worse: it removes `assert` statements and docstrings which is not always what you want. I recommend to avoid this "optimization".